# Motor-Potientiometer read and write, additional power source

Tags: rpi.gpio, wiring

I want to get and set values for a motor potentioneter `ALPS RK16812MG` from a raspberry pi. I found a similar approach [here](https://forum-raspberrypi.de/forum/thread/32123-motorpoti-steuern/) however, the answers in that forum suggest a different wiring with an additional power source. Also, in that thread, there is no wiring for reading the potentiometer value. 
My questions:

- Can the `L 293 D`, mentioned in that thread, also take care of reading the current potentiometer value or do I need another A/D converter there?
- Could you give me an example on how to wire everything properly with an additional power source
- (and, maybe you could explain to me, what this "optical decoupling" is, that the thread is talking about)

---

## Data Sheets

- [ALPS RK16812MG](https://www.buerklin.com/medias/sys_master/download/download/h41/hce/8892317958174.pdf)
- [L293D](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/150000-174999/174003-da-01-en-IC_SCHRITTMOTORTR__L293D__DIP16__STM.pdf)

Comment: You really need to link to the specs of the device.  I have no idea how a motor potentiometer is used.  The L293D is a motor driver chip - it is used to supply power to a motor.  You need an ADC to read a potentiometer.

Comment: I have added the data sheets for both components, if anything else is not clear - please tell me.

Comment: Is the following correct?  "The ALPS is used to twist a shaft, either manually or by applying power.  The current shaft angle can be determined by reading the potentiometer resistance."  Might be useful to add your usage to the question.